# Making geotiff and reprojecting to EPSG:4326 using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, mercator

My goal is to download a gif file from this webpage:

http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2104.gif

Then crop it to the known latlon bounds of 75N,45S,35W,70E, convert to geotif, and then project to EPSG:4326. The map says "Mer", but how does one figure out what EPSG to use in gdal when converting to geotiff? I've tried many: 3395,3857,3785, etc, but none seem to work properly. Here are the commands I've used:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:3857 -a_ullr -35 75 70 -45 2104_cropped.png 2104_3857.tiff

gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:4326 2104_3857.tiff 2104_4326.tiff
```

I get no warning with gdalwarp, but the image never warps, it stays the same. When i overlay them on the maps that expect EPSG:4326, the maps to don't line up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, crop the image source (coords are expressed in pixels here) with:

```
gdal_translate -srcwin 115 18 1360 2156 2104.gif 2104_cropped.tif
```

Then, transform the known WGS84 coordinates of the upper left and lower right corners to the **"WGS 84 / World Mercator"** projection ([**EPSG:3395**](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3395/)):

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +init=epsg:3395
-35 75
-3896182.18     12890914.14 0.00
70 -45
7792364.36      -5591295.92 0.00
```

Assign the "WGS 84 / World Mercator" projection and the coordinates of the upper left and lower right corners in the same SRS:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:3395 -a_ullr -3896182.18 12890914.14 7792364.36 -5591295.92 2104_cropped.tif 2104_3395.tif
```

Finally, transform the image from the "WGS 84 / World Mercator" projection to EPSG:4326:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 2104_3395.tif 2104_4326.tif
```

This is the graphical result in gvSIG:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Mercator is not the same as Pseudo Mercator used by Google & Co.

Try this "real" Mercator projection:

```
+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would I put all of this in place of EPSG:3857 in both commands?

Comment: Yes, with qoutation marks around the whole string.

Comment: Nope. Still the same offset between the overlay and underlying EPSG:4326 layer. I'm out of ideas. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The `-a_ullr` you enter are in degrees. They should be in the applied CRS.